# Сдвиг вправо, сдвиг влево квадрата, и как сделать, чтобы все это было в ограниченном секторе

Tags: c#

[image][image]
На картинке консоль разбита на три сектора в большой вывод фигур, и они не должны выходить за рамки. Во втором добавление и перемещение последнего добавленного квадрата. Проблема в том, что я не могу создать этот ограниченный сектор, добавить фигуру и заставить двигаться фигуру. У меня получается вывести на экран фигуру, и все, на этом месте я застрял 
**В Main е добавил клавиши для управления они срабатывают но очень медленно. И иногда выдает такую ошибку как на втором скрине, не знаю как исправить.
Сразу извиняюсь за мой русский**.
[Прога профессора как все должно быть](https://yadi.sk/d/jO2KEfZo3GKJ3W)

```
  class SahnePaneli
{
    public SahnePaneli(int genislik, int yukseklik)
    {

    }
    public void KonumAta(int x, int y)
    {

    }
    public void Ciz()
    {
        //функция должна гарантировать, что все четырехугольная (Dortgen) форма, который можно сделать выресуются в область.
    }
    public void AktifSekilAta(Dortgen yeniSekil)
    {

    }

    public void SekilSolaOtele()// активные функции четырехугольные формы используются для перемещения движущегося блока.
    {//Каждый шаг должен быть сделан, когда контроль краш-теста.Активная Форма должна быть столкновением с границей ранее добавленных форм и сцен.
        aktifSekil.SolaOtele();
        if (aktifSekil.X == 0)
            aktifSekil.SagaOtele();

    }


    public void SekilSagaOtele()
    {
        aktifSekil.SolaOtele();
        if (aktifSekil.X == 0)
            aktifSekil.SagaOtele();
    }// вправо
    public void SekilYukariOtele() { }//вверх
    public void SekilAsagiOtele() { }//вниз
    public bool SekillerCarpisiyormu()
    {
        return false;// на первое время сделал так что бы не мигала
    }//проверка на то что бы последняя фигура при предвижении не влезла на предыдущюю

    private int genislik;
    private int yukseklik;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Dortgen cizimAlani;
    private Dortgen aktifSekil;
    private int sekilSayisi;
    private int maksimumSekilSayisi;
    private Dortgen[] sekiller;
    //cizimAlani новый объект используется для рисования границы сцены
    //sekiller массив должен держать в себе ссылки класса Dikdortgen. размер этого каталога должен быть максимум 100.
    //maksimumSekilSayi квота вместимости значений из Dortgen. 
    //Это значение должно быть меньше, чем 100. 
    //(Это значение может быть установлено в функции конструктора)
    //sekilsayi, декорации был добавлен, чтобы указать количество четырехугольника. 
    //Каждый четырехугольник добавляют значение этой переменной должно быть увеличено на 1.
    //aktifsekil содержит значени Dortgen Последнего добавленного объекта.

}
class BilgiPaneli// тут  информациооная область (правая нижнея область)
{
    public BilgiPaneli(int genislik, int yukseklik)
    {

    }//тут высота и ширина инфо области
     //Функция Ciz() рисует поле BilgiPaneli.
     //Функция BilgiCiz() предоставляет информацию, принадлежащую к активной форме в области рисования BilgiPaneli.
     //Эта функция   должна быть вызвана внутри Ciz().
    public void KonumAta(int x, int y)
    {

    }
    public void Ciz()
    {

    }
    public void BilgiCiz()
    {

    }
    public void SekilAta(Dortgen sekil)
    {

    }

    private Dortgen aktifSekil;
    private Dortgen cizimAlani;

    private int genislik;
    private int yukseklik;
    private int x;
    private int y;

}
class KontrolPaneli//тут панель контроля (верхняя правая область)
{
    //Функция Ciz() рисует поле KontrolPaneli .
    //Функция MenuCiz() отвечает за прорисовку значений KontrolPaneli
    //Эта функция   должна быть вызвана внутри Ciz().
    public KontrolPaneli(int genislik, int yukseklik)
    {

    }


    public void Ciz()
    {

    }
    public void KonumAta(int x, int y)
    {

    }
    public void MenuCiz()
    {

    }//тут вывод меню 


    private int genislik;
    private int yukseklik;

    private int x;
    private int y;

    private Dortgen cizimAlani;

}
class RastgeleSayi//Рандомное числа
{
    public static int SayiUret(int min, int max)
    {
        if (rastgele == null)
            rastgele = new Random();

        return rastgele.Next(min, max);
    }

    private static Random rastgele;
}
class KarakterSeti // сдесь символы для постройки квадрата
{
    public static char SolUstKose = '╔';
    public static char SagUstKose = '╗';
    public static char Duz = '═';
    public static char Dikey = '║';
    public static char SolAltKose = '╚';
    public static char SagAltKose = '╝';
}
class Dortgen
{
    public Dortgen() // здесь зодается высота и ширина рандомными числами, цвет так же и кординаты так же рандомно
    {
        this.genislik = RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(2, 20);
        this.yukseklik = RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(2, 10);
        renk = (ConsoleColor)RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(1, 15);
        x = RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(1, 79);
        y = RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(1, 79);
    }


    public Dortgen(int xSinir, int ySinir)
    {
        this.xSinir = xSinir;
        this.ySinir = ySinir;
    }
    public void ciz() // тут все собирается 
    {
        ConsoleColor ilkrenk = Console.ForegroundColor;
        TepeCiz();
        DikeyCiz();
        TabanCiz();
    }


    public void DikeyCiz()//сдесь вертикальные столбци
    {
        ConsoleColor ilkrenk = Console.ForegroundColor;
        for (int i = 1; i < yukseklik; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + i);
            Console.Write(KarakterSeti.Dikey);

            Console.SetCursorPosition(x + genislik + 1, y + i);
            Console.Write(KarakterSeti.Dikey);
        }
        Console.ForegroundColor = ilkrenk;
    }
    public void TepeCiz()//сдесь нижняя часть квадрата
    {

        Console.ForegroundColor = renk;

        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);

        Console.Write(KarakterSeti.SolUstKose);
        for (int i = 0; i < genislik; i++)
            Console.Write(KarakterSeti.Duz);
        Console.Write(KarakterSeti.SagUstKose);


    }
    public void TabanCiz()//здесь верхняя часть
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + yukseklik);
        Console.Write(KarakterSeti.SolAltKose);
        for (int i = 0; i < genislik; i++)
            Console.Write(KarakterSeti.Duz);
        Console.Write(KarakterSeti.SagAltKose);
    }

    public void SolaOtele()//сдесь я попытался сделать что бы двигалось в право и влево и вниз верх
    {
        x -= 1;
    }
    public void SagaOtele()
    {
        x += 1;
    }
    public void YukariOtele()
    {
        y -= 1;
    }
    public void AsagiOtele()
    {
        y += 1;
    }

    public void boyutAta(int genislik, int yukseklik)
    {
        this.genislik = genislik;
        this.yukseklik = yukseklik;
    }
    public void RenkAta(ConsoleColor renk)
    {
        this.renk = renk;
    }


    private int genislik;
    private int yukseklik;
    private ConsoleColor renk;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int xSinir;
    private int ySinir;

    public int X
    {
        get{ return x; }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dortgen dkg = new Dortgen();
        while (true)
        {

            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.W)
            {
                dkg.YukariOtele();
            }
            else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.A)
            {
                dkg.SolaOtele();
            }
            else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D)
            {
                dkg.SagaOtele();
            }
            else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                dkg.AsagiOtele();
            }
            Console.Clear();
            dkg.ciz();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сектор - это часть круга, у вас наверное имеется ввиду границы прямоугольника ("квадрата") Если прямоугольники вы опишите стандартным классом Rectangle можете использовать функцию IntersectsWith

Comment: да да должен быть не большой квадрат что бы внутри него двигать квадрат. Простите за мой русский))

Comment: Класс Rastgele только для координата, цвета и ширины высоты квадрата. нужно в методе Dortgen(int xSinir, int ySinir) задать границы как на рисунке. Я ни как не могу это сделать.

Comment: Используйте класс `System.Drawing.Rectangle`. Там есть нужные вам ф-ции.

Comment: @nick_n_a это все в консоли если верить коду. С использованием символов псевдографики, давненько такого не видел, так что Rectangle тут мимо. Тащить в консоль еще и GDI+ как то странно.

Comment: @MansurMahmutov опишите проблему немного подробнее. Ошибки в русском не страшно, потом поправим

Comment: @rdom Это домашка по ООП так вот кроме вывода квадрата с использованием символов и сдига его по координатам оси тут нужно еще разделить консоль на три области как на картинке.

Comment: В большой области нужно чтоб они появлялись двигались во второй та что с верху в левом углу там как бы постоянное меню, при нажатие на клавишу (E) она добавляет фигуры(мах 100) в рандом месте с рандомными высотой и шириной двигать можно только фигуру которая добавлена последней, при нажатии на клавиши (W - вверх, A - влево, S - вправо, D - вниз)   производится движение. Последняя область показывает координаты Х и У, высоту, ширину и цвет. Координаты Х У меняются когда квадрат двигается.  Надеюсь смог объяснить))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса, я понял что у вас две проблемы.

1. Скорость вывода и реакции консоли. Об этом я уже отвечал тут, оставлю ссылку на ответ. В принципе, все необходимое там описано, надеюсь с чтением проблем не возникнет, если что оставьте комментарий, постараемся найти взаимно понятный язык. [Про особенности работы с консолью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607263/198316)
2. Вычисление допустимых размеров и координат фигуры, чтобы она не вылетала за границы отведенной области.

Для исправления ошибки, достаточно немного изменить параметры генерации фигур.

```
public Dortgen()
{
    this.genislik = RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(2, 20);
    this.yukseklik = RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(2, 10);
    renk = (ConsoleColor)RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(1, 15);
    x = RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(1, areaWidth - this.genislik + 1);
    y = RastgeleSayi.SayiUret(1, areaHeight - this.yukseklik + 1);
}
```

где:
`areaWidth` - ширина области вывода, меньше либо равно `Console.WindowWidth`
`areaHeight` - высота области вывода меньше либо равно `Console.WindowHeight`

аналогично проверяем пару (x,y) на допустимость значений.

```
if((x > 0) && (x < areaWidth - this.genislik + 1)
  && (y > 0) && (y < areaHeight - this.yukseklik + 1))
{
    //логика движения или чего-то еще
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Всем)) Закончил я проект спасибо.