# Присвоение цвета посреди вывода в консоль

Tags: c#

У нас есть код:

```
Console.Write ("Что то");
```

Мне нужно, что бы "Что" было зеленым, а "то" красным. Да, можно разделить.

```
Console.ForegroundColoe = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.Write ("Что");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write ("то");
```

Но хотелось-бы менять цвет консоли "посреди" вывода в консоль. Для чего это нужно? В зависимости от условия нам нужно вывести некоторые значения в консоль повторно.
Например (крас)1(зел)23, (зел)1(крас)2(зел)3, (зел)12(крас)3.
Есть бы они нужны были одного цвета, то все просто:

```
Console.Write(new string ('123', колвораз));
```

А так... Да, можно создать несколько если, и... (Пример)

```
int writecount = 0;
if(чтото = чтото)
{ do
  {
   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
   Console.Write("1");
   Console.Fore...
   ++writecount;
  }while(writecount != чтото);
```

Но у меня не самое простое приложение, и большое повторение do (а у меня числа там большие) просто вешает консоль намертво.
Как можно вклинится в вывод и прописать цвет? Или же подскажите другое решение данной проблемы, желательно как можно менее ресурсно затратное.

Comment: Скорее всего, я не правильно вас понял, но идея у меня такая: Задать цвет для определенной группы цифр (слов), к примеру 1,3,5,7 - зеленый, 2.4.6.8 - красный и т.д. Ну а после уже можешь задать условие, если такая то группа была красным, то сменить на другой цвет

Comment: Не нужно язык указывать в заголовке, для этого есть метка.

Comment: Нет, того что вы хотите "из коробки" нет. Собственно все что вы можете сделать - перенести раздельный вывод в отдельный класс (два решения уже предложены), но в любом случае это будет все тот же раздельный вывод и переключение цвета по требованию.

Comment: Ну и посмотрите еще [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607263/198316), там описаны почти все проблемы с консолью, которые нужно решить, и есть подсказки как решить. Основная причина медленной работы у консольных приложений - скорость вывода самой консоли. Если вы руками не оптимизировали вывод в консоль - будут тормоза.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
using System;

namespace ColourOutput
{
    public static class ColourWriter
    {
        public static ConsoleColor defaultColor { get; set; } = ConsoleColor.White;

        public static void Write(string text)
        {
            foreach (var word in text.Split(',', ' '))
            {
                if (word[0] == '{')
                {
                    ColorHelper(word.Substring(3, word.Length - 3), word[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(word + " ");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ColorHelper(string word, char color)
        {
            switch (color)
            {
                case 'G':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.Write(word + " ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = defaultColor;
                    break;
                case 'R':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write(word + " ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = defaultColor;
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.Write(word + " ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = defaultColor;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ColourWriter.Write("{G}Зеленый,{R}Красный - {B}Это цвета \n (С)");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

До юзабельного вида думаю сами доведете)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мб я что-либо не допонял, но у меня ругается в *Main* на ColourWriter.Write. Имя "ColourWriter" не существует в данном контексте.

Answer (score 4):

Не уверен, что я понял вашу мысль, но в коммент много кода не засунешь, так что отпишу как ответ.

Я сделал небольшой потоконебезопасный писатель цветом в консоль (с буфером)

```
class ColoredConsoleWriter
{
    private List<WriteItem> _inner = new List<WriteItem>();

    public void Append(string text, ConsoleColor color)
    {
        var last = _inner.LastOrDefault();
        if (last != null && last.Color == color)
        {
            last.Text+=text;
            return;
        }

        _inner.Add(new WriteItem() {Text=text, Color = color});
    }

    public void AppendLine(string text, ConsoleColor color)
    {
        Append(text + Environment.NewLine, color);
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        var local = _inner;

        foreach (var item in local)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = item.Color;
            Console.Write(item.Text);
        }

        _inner = new List<UserQuery.ColoredConsoleWriter.WriteItem>();      
    }

    class WriteItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public ConsoleColor Color { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Залил в него 10000 элементов текста

```
void Sample()
{
    var writer = new ColoredConsoleWriter();

    var random = new Random();
    var colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)).OfType<ConsoleColor>().ToArray();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        writer.Append(i.ToString(), colors[random.Next(colors.Length)]);
    }

    writer.Flush();
}
```

Запустил всё это добро

```
void Main()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    Sample();   
    sw.Stop();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed: {sw.Elapsed}");
}
```

Отработало примерно за секунду
[image: результат]

Надеюсь, это чем то поможет вам :)

Comment: `в коммент много кода не засунешь` — так и не зачем ответы в комментарии засовывать. :)

Comment: Кстати, картинка душевно выглядит.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я просто не уверен, что это именно то, о чем спрашивает автор. А картинка и мне самому нравится :)

Comment: @tym32167 Да, это. Картинка действительно душевная.

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать [управляющие символы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI#%D0%A6%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0). Они [поддерживаются](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) в последних версиях Винды Десятки. Но сперва их поддержку нужно включить (пример взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44574274/5045688)).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        const uint ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 4;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            uint mode;
            GetConsoleMode(handle, out mode);
            mode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
            SetConsoleMode(handle, mode);

            const string UNDERLINE = "\x1B[4m";
            const string RESET = "\x1B[0m";
            const string RED = "\x1b[31m";
            const string GREEN = "\x1b[32m";

            Console.WriteLine("Some " + UNDERLINE + "underlined" + RESET + " text");
            Console.WriteLine(RED + "Привет " + GREEN + "Мир!" + RESET);
        }
    }
}
```