# Цветные символы в строке

Tags: c#, консоль

как можно с помощью C# сделать отдельные символы в строке консоли цветными?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688241/184217

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace CSrharpApplicationTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string s = "Hello world!";
            foreach (var item in s)
            {
                // Используем 16, а не 15, так как rnd.Next не включает 16
                // в диапазон случайных чисел. Максимальное значение ConsoleColor
                // - это 15.
                Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)rnd.Next(16);
                Console.Write(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод строки случайными цветами посимвольно. Используется явное приведение `int -> ConsoleColor`. Обращаю внимания на то, что перечисление обычно базируется на типе [целочисленном типе](https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2017/12/27/enumerations_ru/#q06) (хотя средствами рефлексиями, можно вытворять что угодно, но это плохая идея).