# Яркий шрифт в консоли на С#

Tags: c#, консоль, текст, цвета

Как на С# сделать яркий шрифт? Например, устанавливаю зелёный шрифт, и я хочу, чтобы был ещё светло-зелёный ещё. Это помогает при создании меню для консольной игры, где обычный зеленый - просто возможный вариант, а светло-зеленый - то, что хочет выбрать игрок.
Эта возможность есть на С++:

```
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, FOREGROUND_GREEN); //просто зелёный
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUNG_INTENSITY); //светло-зеленый
```

Comment: если что, потом могу добавить скрин с примером, если вы не поймете

Comment: ¿А что мешает вызвать эти же функции из C# посредством pinvoke или через какую-нибудь обертку?

Comment: `ConsoleColor.Green` и `ConsoleColor.DarkGreen`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688241/179763

Comment: по поводу консольных менюшек - есть вот такой [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1375879/373567).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите возможности класса `Console`, он много всякого умеет.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Default color");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Green intensity color");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
    Console.WriteLine("Green color");
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.WriteLine("Default color");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Еще как вариант использовать dll'ку Pastel: https://github.com/silkfire/Pastel — тут можно создавать свои собственные цвета rgb

Comment: @ValeriyMihaylovskiy можно активировать VT100, и без библиотек любые штуки эти вытворять вообще используя только запись байт в stdout.