# Падающие символы

Tags: c#, .net

Требуется написать программу которая будет выводит цепочку падающих символов. Первый снизу символ должен быть белый, второй зеленый, остальные темно-зеленые.
Проблема в том, что цепочку падающих символов вывел, а как смещать цепочку символов вниз так и не понял. Если я правильно понял то, надо установить курсор в начало строки и потом уже как-то смещать её вниз.

```
using System;
namespace Task1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int lenghtStr = rand.Next(1, 11);
            char[] column = new char[lenghtStr];
            for (int i = 0; i < lenghtStr; i++)
            {
                column[i] = (char)rand.Next('A', 'Z');
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < lenghtStr; i++)
            {
                if (i == (lenghtStr - 1))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.WriteLine(column[i]);
                }
                else if (i == (lenghtStr - 2))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine(column[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                    Console.WriteLine(column[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607263/198316?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Отображение работы программы]

Создадим такой класс Символа

```
class Sign
{
    //генератор будем использовать в этом классе и снаружи
    public static Random RandomGen = new Random();

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение случайного знака
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private char GetSign()
    {
        int t = RandomGen.Next(10);
        if (t <= 2)
            return (char)('0' + RandomGen.Next(10));
        else if (t <= 4)
            return (char)('a' + RandomGen.Next(27));
        else if (t <= 6)
            return (char)('A' + RandomGen.Next(27));
        else
            return (char)(RandomGen.Next(32, 255));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение случайного символа белого цвета
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">позиция слева</param>
    /// <param name="top">позиция от верха</param>
    public void ShowWhiteSign(int left, int top)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        Console.Write(GetSign());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение случайного символа зеленого цвета
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">позиция слева</param>
    /// <param name="top">позиция от верха</param>
    public void ShowGreenSign(int left, int top)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        Console.Write(GetSign());

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение случайного символа темного зеленого цвета
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">позиция слева</param>
    /// <param name="top">позиция от верха</param>
    public void ShowDarkGreenSign(int left, int top)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        Console.Write(GetSign());

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение пробела в нужном месте
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">позиция слева</param>
    /// <param name="top">позиция от верха</param>
    public void ShowSpaceSign(int left, int top)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        Console.Write(' ');
    }
}
```

Класс Отображателя такой

```
class SignsShower
{
    private int _heightWindow;
    private int _widthWindow;
    private int[] _widthPosSimple;
    private int[] _widthPosAddition;

    private readonly Sign _sign = new Sign();

    //ctor
    public SignsShower() : this((Console.WindowWidth - 1), Console.WindowHeight)
    { }
    /// <summary>
    /// Отображатель символов
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="windowWidth">ширина консольного окна минус 1</param>
    /// <param name="windowHeight">высота консольного окна</param>
    public SignsShower(int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
    {
        Initialization(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    }

    private void Initialization(int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
    {
        //получаем высоту окна
        _heightWindow = windowHeight;

        int h1 = _heightWindow / 2; //половина высоты
        int h2 = _heightWindow / 4; //четверть высоты

        //ширина окна
        _widthWindow = windowWidth;

        //два массива размером в ширину окна
        _widthPosSimple = new int[_widthWindow];
        _widthPosAddition = new int[_widthWindow];

        //заполнение массивов случайными числами
        for (int i = 0; i < _widthWindow; i++)
        {
            _widthPosSimple[i] = Sign.RandomGen.Next(_heightWindow);

            int k = (i % 11 != 10) ? 2 : 1;
            int min = h2 * k;
            int max = h1 * k;
            _widthPosAddition[i] = Sign.RandomGen.Next(min, max);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение символов в случайных позициях с необх.цветом
    /// </summary>
    public void SignShow()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _widthWindow; i++)
        {
            if (_widthPosSimple[i] < 10)
            {
                //отображение темного символа
                _sign.ShowDarkGreenSign(i, _widthPosSimple[i]);
            }
            else if (_widthPosSimple[i] < 25)
            {
                //отображение зеленого символа
                _sign.ShowGreenSign(i, _widthPosSimple[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                //отображаем белый символ
                _sign.ShowWhiteSign(i, _widthPosSimple[i]);
            }

            //сдвигаем координату по высоте для отображения в след. цикле вызова SignShow()
            _widthPosSimple[i] = CheckNextHeightPosition(_widthPosSimple[i] + 1, _heightWindow);

            //пробельный символ
            int next = _widthPosSimple[i] - _widthPosAddition[i];
            int nextPos = CheckNextHeightPosition(next, _heightWindow);
            _sign.ShowSpaceSign(i, nextPos);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Проверка значения след.позиции
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next">значение след.положения по высоте</param>
    /// <param name="height">общая допустимая высота</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private int CheckNextHeightPosition(int next, int height)
    {
        next = next % height;

        if (next < 0)
        {
            return next + height;
        }
        else
        {
            return next;
        }

    }
}
```

Теперь включим в работу эти классы так

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //отображатель
        SignsShower signsShower = new SignsShower();

        //готовим консоль
        Console.Clear();
        Console.CursorVisible = false;

        //в бесконечном цикле с вычисляемой задержкой отображаем
        int ms = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            //засекаем время
            DateTime timeMark = DateTime.Now;
            //отображаем символы
            signsShower.SignShow();

            //задержка
            ms = 10 - (int)((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - timeMark)).TotalMilliseconds;
            if (ms > 0) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms);
        }

    }
```

Не знаю, правильно ли я вас понял, но по крайней мере у вас теперь есть от чего плясать.

Comment: Вы случайно не выступали техническим консультантом фильма «Матрица»?

Comment: Походу так оно и есть:)

Answer (score 2):

Конечно моё решение не такое красивое и лаконичное как у @Bulson, но думаю оно всё таки тоже имеет право на существование.  Захотелось придумать что-то своё, извращённое так скажем;)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Task1
{
    class Program
    {
        static object locker = new object();
        static int Generate(int a, int b) // Метод генерирования рандомных чисел
        {
            Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
            return rand.Next(a, b);
        }
        static void Matrix(object numberColumn) // метод вывода столбцов с символами, в качестве параметра принимает позицию строки курсора
        {
            while(true) 
            { 
            int lenghtColumn = 0; 
            int position = 0; // Позиция столбца курсора
            const int maxLenght = 40; // максимальная длинна столбца
            Random rand = new Random();
            int count = Generate(25, 39); //длинна столбца 
            Thread.Sleep(555);
                for (int i = 0; i != maxLenght + count; i++)
                {
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black; //Задаём чёрный цвет тексту
                        for (int j = 0; j <= position; j++) // В цикле закрашиваем символы черным квадратом
                        {
                            Console.SetCursorPosition((int)numberColumn, j); // Устанавливаем позицию курсора
                            Console.WriteLine("█"); // Так как мы поменяли цвет текста в консоли на чёрный, то квадрат не будет красным
                        }
                        if (lenghtColumn < count && position != 40) 
                        {
                            ++lenghtColumn;
                        }
                            else if (position == maxLenght)
                                {
                                    --lenghtColumn;
                                }
                        if (lenghtColumn >= 3)
                        {
                            for (int k = position - (lenghtColumn - 1); k <= position - 2; k++)
                            {
                                Console.SetCursorPosition((int)numberColumn, k);
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                                Console.WriteLine((char)rand.Next('A', 'z'));
                            }
                        }
                            if (lenghtColumn >= 2)
                            {
                                Console.SetCursorPosition((int)numberColumn, position - 1);
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                                Console.WriteLine((char)rand.Next('A', 'z'));
                            }
                                if (lenghtColumn >= 1)
                                {
                                    Console.SetCursorPosition((int)numberColumn, position);
                                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                                    Console.WriteLine((char)rand.Next('A', 'z'));
                                if (position != maxLenght) position++;
                                }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.SetWindowSize(100, 42);     
            Thread t;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                t = new Thread(Matrix);
                t.Start(i);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```