# C# Графика(прямая линия и круг)

Tags: c#, graph

Можно ли в консоли нарисовать прямую линию и круг?(не в форме, где нужно добавлять специальный блок, где можно рисовать) Если да, тогда хотелось бы увидеть короткий пример. Так как не могу ничего найти в поисковике или других ресурсов!

Comment: Можно, но зачем? :) (используя псевдографику) Стандартные классы не предлагают такой возможности

Comment: Прикольные штуки оказывается можно делать: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33538527/5752652

Comment: @AK действительно интересные

Comment: Мне для личного развития нужно!

Comment: Буду рад самому простому примеру, для начала

Comment: Сейчас все всё рисуют на готовых библиотеках, поэтому и не можете ничего найти. Хотя там все просто на самом деле. Если что-то осталось не до конца понятным, пишите в комментариях или отдельном вопросе, но сначала попробуйте разобраться сами, там все довольно просто, если не браться сходу за кривые n-го порядка и прочие математические изыски, но это уже совсем другая тема, и математику надо знать на соответствующем уровне, на пальцах объяснять будет слишком сложно и громоздко.

Comment: @AK да, прикольные. Там много чего можно, и градиенты, и "ну почти 3D" (сам делал, очень давно правда). Только ни кто этим не занимается - "среднему потребителю" "графон" подавай "на уровне", а то что кроме картинки ничего больше нет в большинстве случаев, как бы не важно. Так что это вымирающий вид искусства, к большому сожалению.

Comment: Думаю, такое возможно. Я нашёл код, который позволяет строить графики в `C++`. Если это Вам как-то поможет, то я могу скинуть его...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос пересекается с другим моим [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607263/198316), настоятельно рекомендую прочитать и его тоже.

Посмотрите на консольный вывод немного под другим углом и увидите наличие всех графических возможностей, за исключением готовых библиотек. Картинка состоит из пикселей, сейчас они почти квадратные (но так было не всегда, привет от ДВК и прочих "динозавров" с растровым дисплеем). Что может заменить пиксели в консоли? Правильно, символы. Да придется установить шрифт "по-квадратнее", что-то вроде точечного шрифта 8х9 или использовать пары символов шрифта 5х12,или просто смириться с тем, что пиксели у вас прямоугольные.

Далее есть варианты:

1. [ASCII-графика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Можно нагуглить огромное количество изображений выполненных в данной технике. В период дисплеев на основе знакогенератора, это был единственно возможный вариант представления графической информации. Ключевая особенность - для формирования изображения и передачи цвета используются алфавитно-цифровые знаки. C# использует юникод - поэтому выбор печатных знаков огромен.
2. Табличная графика, или [псевдографика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Это особый набор символов, созданный для оформления таблиц. Тут в общем-то ничего особо интересного пожалуй нет, но если нужны таблицы, прямоугольники, вертикальные и горизонтальные линии  что-то лучше придумать тоже довольно сложно.
3. Особая версия пиксель-арта в ультра-низком разрешении (по умолчанию 80х25, настраивается) и ограничением в 16 цветов. Количество оттенков цвета можно увеличить в несколько раз, если использовать для вывода особые символы в сочетании с цветом фона, например как в ответе по ссылке в комментарии [@A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k).

Выбор стиля естественно за вами.

---

Так как готовых библиотек нет, примитивы вроде линий и окружностей придется рисовать самостоятельно. Из доступного у нас есть только рисование точки (с помощью вывода символа разумеется). Рисование вертикальных и горизонтальных линий не составляет проблем. Просто смещаем курсор по одной координате и рисуем очередной символ-пиксель.

С кривыми или наклонными прямыми придется вспоминать математику. Выглядеть будет как-то так:

[image: Вот как-то так оно будет выглядеть]

Точки линии сначала вычисляются, для этого понадобится знать формулу кривой или вывести ее из начальных параметров (точки начала и конца для линий, координаты центра и радиус для окружности и т.д.). Так как не все значения будут целыми, а координаты даже обычных пикселей строго целые, придется вычислить масштабные коэффициенты и привести исходные дробные значения к целым в соответствующем масштабе. После, по полученному массиву точек в целых координатах выводим символы пиксели в консоль.

---

Ну и небольшой пример для демонстрации. Возьмем самый простой примитив - наклонную линию, чтобы показать общий принцип и, при этом, не уходить глубоко в математику.

Исходные данные:
дефолтный размер экрана консоли - 80х25 знаков;
рисовать будем диагональную линию из нижнего левого угла в правый верхний;   координаты начала линии - `double x1 = 0, y1 = 24;`
координаты конца линии - `double x2 = 79, y2 = 0;`
знак пикселя - `'*'`

Прямую можно задать коэффициентом смещения по x при единичном смещении по y или наоборот.

```
double dx = x2 - x1;//79 - 0 = 79
double dy = y2 - y1;//0 - 24 = -24
```

Теперь нормализуем смещения к единице, для этого разделим полученные значения на модуль наибольшего из них.

```
double maxDelta = Math.Abs(Math.Max(dx, dy));
dx = dx / maxDelta;
dy = dy / maxDelta;
```

Считаем масштабный коэффициент, чтобы вся линия уместилась на видимой части консоли.

```
double xScale = (Math.Max(x1, x2) > (Console.WindowWidth - 1)) 
                    ? Math.Max(x1, x2) / (Console.WindowWidth - 1) 
                    : 1;
double yScale = (Math.Max(y1, y2) > (Console.WindowHeight - 1)) 
                    ? Math.Max(y1, y2) / (Console.WindowHeight - 1) 
                    : 1;
double scale = Math.Max(xScale, yScale);
```

Теперь можно рисовать линию.

```
//настоящие координаты точек линии
double x = x1;
double y = y1;
//целые координаты пикселей для точек линии
int graphX = (int)Math.Round(x / scale);
int graphY = (int)Math.Round(y / scale);

while(graphX >= 0 && graphX < Console.WindowWidth 
    && graphY >= 0 && graphY < Console.WindowHeight)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(graphX, graphY);
    Console.Write('*');
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    graphX = (int)Math.Round(x / scale);
    graphY = (int)Math.Round(y / scale);
}
```

И получаем вот такую картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, техника древняя и довольно простая. Применяется не только в консольной графике, но и в обычной, при по-пиксельном рисовании. Все остальные примитивы обрабатываются похожим образом, либо с предварительным полным расчетом точек линии в массиве для сложных кривых. С окружностью и эллипсом придется вспомнить или подучить базовую тригонометрию, а именно синусы и косинусы.