# C# Как заменить последнюю строку в консоли другой строкой?

Tags: c#, консоль

Программа будет выводить строку с текстом в консоль, а по нажатию клавиши текст на этой строке должен будет заменяться другим. Как мне это реализовать, в документации не смог найти ничего нужного.

Comment: Запомните позицию "курсора" где должен быть соответствующий текст (напишите `Console.Cursor` и найдете все нужное), а затем, когда хотите переписать там текст, установите курсор на нужную позицию через `SetCursorPosition()` (ну или напрямую нужному свойству) и пишите через `Write`, все.  Если вы переписываете только что написанную строку, то напишите `\r` в начале строки, это поставит курсор в начало (прим: если циклом вывести `Console.Write($"\r{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");`, то будет 1 строка с изменяющимся временем).

Comment: Просто оставлю это тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607263/198316 Текста конечно много, но может на толкнет на нужные мысли

Answer (score 0):

@EvgeniyZ уже ответил, но почему то не оформил ответ как ответ, поэтому это сделаю я:

Нам необходимо вначале запомнить позицию **курсора** (место, откуда печатается текст), после чего мы можем напечатать нужное нам сообщение. Если мы хотим его перезаписать, то мы просто возвращаем позицию курсора обратно. Вот пример кода:

```cs
Console.Write("Clicks: ");
for (var i = 0; ; i++)
{
    var cursorPosition = Console.GetCursorPosition();
    Console.Write(i); 
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorPosition.Left, cursorPosition.Top);
}
```